# Detech links in WebView

Tags: android, webview

My objective is to set `auto detection` of `phone number` and `links` inside a `WebView`, and if user doing a long press on number phone for example, a dialog appear to confirm the call

Comment: Hope this will help you: [Check This Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9744390/make-webviews-auto-links-visible) [Check This one also](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4788461/handling-links-in-a-webview)

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by using following lines of coed.

```
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            Log.d(TAG,"shouldOverrideUrlLoading url: "+url);
            if( url.startsWith("http:") || url.startsWith("https:") ) {
                return false;
            }

            // Otherwise allow the OS to handle it
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
            mcContext.startActivity( intent ); 
            return true;

        }
```