# Passing data from one activity to another in Android

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to pass a value from one Activity to another in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3510649/how-to-pass-a-value-from-one-activity-to-another-in-android)

I have an activity with a list of titles and their bodies(content) (list6 example from ApiDemos). And I have an activity, where I add a note. When I click on "Add" button, I want the title of my note to appear on the list. Same with body. The problem is, that in List activity there are two String[] arrays with predefined hard-coded titles and bodies. What should I do to be able to add my own new titles with a content instead of having these hard-coded values? 
I know I must use intents with startActivityForResult, but that's probably all I know...

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3510649/how-to-pass-a-value-from-one-activity-to-another-in-android

Comment: So I don't need arrays at all? More specific answer would be just great.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You have two option:

### 1) make the listview and the two arraylists static

This way you can use the same instances of it from the activity with add button and modify the listview as:

```
FirstActivity.listTitlesArrayList.add(listTitleString);
FirstActivity.listDescriptionArraylist.add(listDescriptionString);//this is probably your note
FirstActivity.listView.invalidateViews();
```

### 2)if you want to use intents:

while going to the ListActivity pass data by..

```
intent.putExtra("Title", listTitleString);
intent.putExtra("Content", listDescriptionString);
startActivity(intent);
```

and to recover it  in second activity use:

```
title= getIntent().getExtras().getString("Title");
```

...and so on..

Comment: Thank you. I gonna use the second option.

Comment: The program runs, but there are several problems... In the second activity instead of string values I get sth totally different - "android.widget.EditText@4051fa30" as a title and "android.widget.EditText@405208c0" as a body. Also, I want to add titles and bodies dynamically to my arrays...In the first activity I have: http://codeviewer.org/view/code:18fb and in the second: http://codeviewer.org/view/code:18fc

Comment: Please, write me on tonia.tkachuk@gmail.com as this topis is closed already =(

Comment: hey you are wrongly getting the text from editbox. This is how you do it.:
 intent.putExtra("Title", titleEdit.getText().toString());

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to [share data between activities](http://developer.android.com/resources/faq/framework.html#3).

In your case probably the easiest way is to have a reference to list in Application. This answer summs it up nicelly: [Making data obtained in one activity available to all the activities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5295122/making-data-obtained-in-one-activity-available-to-all-the-activities/5295249#5295249)