# How to jump from one activity to another particular activity in Android?

Tags: android

I have 3 activities in Android like activity_A,activity_B and activity_C. Calling sequences like this activity_A  >>>>>>> activity_B >>>>>> activity_C. Currently I am in activity_C and now I want to jump directly to activity_A without entering into activity_B and I also have to pass some data.

HOW ???? Please give some piece of code for it!!!

Thanks in Advance !!!
Arthur

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add a new copy of Activity_A on top of the stack, just call it the same way as you did before. Otherwise, choose a [launch mode](http://d.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode) depending on what you want the first copy of Activity_A to do. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497502/passing-data-from-one-activity-to-another-in-android/5497907#5497907) (method #2) for an explanation of passing data between activities.

Answer (score 0):

You can use similar code as you used to get from A>>>B and B>>>C.

Or you can use `finish()` to exit your Activity.  In your case, you'd set a flag in C to tell B to finish then call `finish()` in C.  In B, look for that flag in the `onResume()` method and `finish()` B if it exists.

Answer (score 0):

From your ActivityC code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityA.class);
intent.putExtra("a key string", data);
startActivity(intent);
```

In ActivityA you can recover the data using:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    // here use the getters in extras to retrieve the appropiate data type
    // for example if your data is a String the you would call
    // extras.getString("a key string");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Specific code will depend on the type of data. But you can do something like this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityA.class);
i.putExtra("myData", someData);
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: I would not recommend the usage of the application context in this situation. It can be unpredictable and lead to leaks of application resources http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getApplicationContext()