# Android - Java - Save string on button click

Tags: java, android, android-button

For a school project I want to save the string above the button ('kopen'), after clicking on that button. The textviewID for that string is 'textViewMenu'. The buttonID is 'buttonKopen'

After saving it, I want to display the string in a new activity.

If i press 3 buttons, I need to display all three strings in my new activity.
The name of that new activity is 'MijnBonnen'.

[image: shop layout]

I have no errors, I'm just looking for some help to start
Any help is welcome!

Comment: And what issue did you get???

Comment: I don't know how to start..

Comment: `android sharedpreferences`

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497502/passing-data-from-one-activity-to-another-in-android) might help you. Share your code for more help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `Arraylist` to store the strings

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Then on every button click add the text to to the arraylist  like

```
public void onClick(View v) {

String clickedText;

switch(v.getId())
{
   case R.id.your_1st_button_id:
   clickedText=your_textView.getText().toString();
   break;
   case R.id.your_2nd_button_id:
   clickedText=your_1st_textView.getText().toString();
   break;
   case R.id.your_3rd_button_id:
   clickedText=your_3rd_textView.getText().toString();
   break;

 }

  list.add(clickedText);

}
```

After that send the arraylist as extra with `Intent` using

```
 Intent i=new Intent(this,Second.class);
 i.putStringArrayListExtra("list", ar);
 startActivity(i);
```

Now in the second activity get the arraylist like

```
ArrayList<String> ar1=getIntent().getExtras().getStringArrayList("list");
```

Now from second activity you can access all arraylist data with a for loop

```
 for (String s : ar1){
  Log.d("My array list content: ", s);
 }
```